# Area of Projection of Tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, projection

this is my first post. Here is a question I found in a handout I am reading on 3D geometry.

A plane passes through the midpoints of two skew lines of a regular tetrahedron. The projection of the tetrahedron to the plane produces a quadrilateral with an angle of $60$. What is the ratio of the area of this quadrilateral to the surface area of the original tetrahedron?

I was able to solve the problem using geogebra to model the diagram, but I am unable to prove it. The answer that I found was about $0.3145$. I am really stuck on how to prove an exact answer.

Please help.

*Here is the link to my geogebra model:
https://www.geogebra.org/3d/tjpgzaqb

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Please, give the geogebra figure you have obtained or a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks for having included the Geogebra figure. In my solution, I had made a lot of calculations errors ; I wish the last version is correct...

Answer (score 1):

As we are concerned with a ratio of areas, we can assume that the tetrahedron is inscribed in the cube $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ with vertices

$$B(1,1,1), \ A(-1,-1,1), \ C(1,-1,-1), \ D(-1,1,-1)$$

We have: $\vec{AB} \perp \vec{CD}$ (resp. the upper edge and lower edge). Their midpoints are $E(0,0,1)$, resp $F(0,0,-1)$
A rotation with angle $\alpha$ gives rise to a projection onto the following isosceles trapezoid:

[image]

where the projected points onto the plane are:

$$A_1(-\sqrt{2} \cos \alpha,1), \ B_1(\sqrt{2} \cos \alpha,1), \ C_1(\sqrt{2} \sin \alpha,-1), \ D(-\sqrt{2} \sin \alpha,-1)$$

Indeed, as $\tan \pi/3 = \sqrt{3}$, we must have:

$$\underbrace{\tan \angle C_1D_1A_1}_{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{EF}{|D_1F-A_1E|}$$

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|\cos \alpha - \sin \alpha|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

with a particular solution:

$$\sin(\alpha-\pi/4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\alpha=\pi/4+\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

From there, it is not difficult to find the ratio of areas.

Indeed, the area of the trapezoid is

$$Area \ = \ half basis \ \times \ height \ = \ 2 \sqrt{2}(\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha))$$

$$ \ Area \ = \ 4\cos(\alpha - \pi/4)=4\cos(\arcsin(1/\sqrt{3}))$$

$$ \ Area \ = \ 4\sqrt{2/3}\tag{1}$$

As the lateral area of the tetrahedron is

$$8 \sqrt{3}\tag{2},$$

the final ratio is the quotient of (2) and (1):

$$\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}}\approx 0.2357$$

which is below your estimation...

Comment: That's not a regular tetrahedron. $AB=\sqrt 8, AC=AD=\sqrt 5, BC = BD=3, CD=\sqrt 2$

Comment: @tomi You are right: the fact that taking 4 out of 8 vertices of a cube allows to build a regular tetrahedron is certain, but I have to select the good coordinates !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without trigonometry. Let's take a tetrahedron $ABCD$ where the distance $OO'$ between the midpoints of two skew edges is $2$, and the edges have then a length of $2\sqrt2$. The projection is an isosceles trapezoid $A'B'C'D'$, with altitude $OO'=2$ and bases $a=A'B'$, $b=C'D'$.

[image]

Projecting the figure on a plane perpendicular to $OO'$ (figure below) one realises that triangles $DD'O$ and $BB'O'$ are equal, hence
$OD'^2+O'B'^2=O'B^2$, that is:
$$
a^2+b^2=8.
$$
Moreover, from $\angle O'B'D'=60°$ it follows
$O'B'-OD'=OO'/\sqrt3$, that is:
$$
a-b={4\over\sqrt3}.
$$
Combining the above equations one finds:
$$
a={2\over\sqrt3}(\sqrt2+1),
\quad
b={2\over\sqrt3}(\sqrt2-1)
$$
and from there the area of the trapezoid can be found, leading to a ratio
$$
{\text{area of trapezoid}\over\text{surface area of tetrahedron}}
={\sqrt2\over6}.
$$

[image]

Comment: That's ingenious, I couldn't understand most of the solution.

Comment: @Potato What, for instance?

Comment: @Potato I've just corrected a typo which might have caused some confusion: the right equality is $′′−′=′/\sqrt3$.

Comment: For example, how did you conclude that $DD'O$ and $BB'O'$ are congruent ??

Comment: @Potato They are both right triangles, $O'B=OD$ and $\angle BO'B'=\angle ODD'$ because $BB'\perp OD'$ and $OD\perp O'B$ (here I'm using $\perp$ with skew lines, meaning they have perpendicular directions).

Comment: (+1) Excellent, and happy that our results coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the vertices of the tetrahedron as being:

$A(1,1,1), B(-1,-1,1), C(1,-1,-1)$ and $D(-1,1,-1)$.

Choose $AB$ and $CD$ as being our skew sides.

The midpoints are given by $M(0,0,1)$ and $N(0,0,-1)$

We want a plane that includes these points. Its normal vector $\bf{n}$ must be perpendicular to $\vec{MN}$

$\begin{bmatrix}{x\\y\\z}\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}{0\\0\\2}\end{bmatrix}=0\Rightarrow 2z=0\Rightarrow z=0$

Let $\bf{n}=\begin{bmatrix}{\cos \theta\\ \sin \theta\\ 0}\end{bmatrix}$

Plane is given by $\bf{r}.\begin{bmatrix}{\cos \theta\\ \sin \theta\\0}\end{bmatrix}$$=d$

Since the plane contains $M(0,0,1)$, we know that $d=0$

Plane is given by $\bf{r}.\begin{bmatrix}{\cos \theta\\ \sin \theta\\0}\end{bmatrix}$$=0$

Projections onto this plane can be calculated...

Answer (score 0):

As we are concerned with ratio of areas, we can assume that the tetrahedron is inscribed in the cube $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ with vertices

$$A(1,1,1), \ B(-1,-1,1), \ C(1,0,-1), \ D(0,1,-1)$$

We have: $\vec{AB} \perp \vec{CD}$ (resp. the upper edge and lower edge). Their midpoints are $E(0,0,1)$, resp $F(0,0,-1)$
A rotation with angle $\alpha$ gives rise to a projection onto an isosceles trapezoid with these values:

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution by @tomi, nice coordinates for the tetrahedron can be
chosen as

$A(1,1,1), B(1, -1, -1), C(-1, 1, -1), D(-1, -1, 1) $

Its side length is $2 \sqrt{2}$

Two opposite edges are $AB$ and $CD$, their respective midpoints are

$M = (1, 0, 0) $ and $N = (-1, 0, 0) $

Hence, the line joining $M$ and $N$ is along the $x$-axis.  A plane containing $MN$ must have a unit normal vector perpendicular to $MN$, thus its most general form is

$n = (0, \cos t, \sin t) = (0, c, s) $

where $c = \cos t, s = \sin t $ for some $t$ that we will find.

This is where I depart from @tomi's work.

We can let projection plane pass through the origin without affecting the projected polygon.  In addition, define unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ such that the triple $[u_1, u_2, n] = R$ form an orthonormal basis (i.e. matrix is a rotation matrix).  Two such vectors can be easily picked as $u_1 = [1, 0, 0]^T $ and $u_2 = [0, s, -c]^T $.

Now the projection of the four vertices $A,B,C,D$ on to the $x'y'$ plane is obtained by premultiplying the coordinates by $R^T$, which is given by

$R^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && s && - c \\ 0 && c && s \end{bmatrix} $

The $2D$ coordinates of the projection in coordinate system $R$ are

$A' = (1, s - c) $

$B' = (1, c - s) $

$C' = (-1, s + c ) $

$D' = (-1, -s - c )$

Note that $A'$ and $B'$ are mirror images about the $x'$ axis, so are $C'$ and $D'$.

The angle we're concerned with is the angle between $A'B'$ and $A'C'$ which we want to be $60^\circ$

$A'B' = 2(0, c-s ) $ and $A'C' = 2(-1, c) $

Hence the angle $\phi $ between them satisfies

$\cos \phi = \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{(A'B') \cdot (A'C') }{\| A'B' \| \|A'C'\| } = \dfrac{ c (c - s) }{ | c - s| \sqrt{1 + c^2 } } = \text{sgn}(c - s) \dfrac{c }{\sqrt{1+c^2}}$

Assuming $\text{sgn}(c-s)$ to be $+1$ to simplify the equation, we end up with

$\sqrt{1+c^2} = 2 c \Rightarrow c = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \Rightarrow s = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$

Since we want $\text{sgn}(c - s) $ to be $+1$ we have to take the sine to be negative.

Now the area of the projected trapezoid resulting is

$A = (1 - (-1)) \dfrac{1}{2} (\|A'B'\| + \|C'D'\|) =  2(c - s) + 2(-s - c) = -4 s = 4 \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} $

The area of the tetrahedron is $A_T = 4 \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdot (2 \sqrt{2})^2 = 8\sqrt{3} $

Hence the ratio of areas is $\dfrac{ \sqrt{2} }{6} $