# Determine whether a spline curve describes an elliptical arc

Tags: conic-sections, curvature, spline, programming

I'm currently writing software which analyses STEP files to hunt for engineered parts with particular shapes. The software uses Open Cascade which presents me with topological and geometrical objects in a BREP representation. When this gives me explicit cylindrical and toroidal surfaces, and explicit circles, ellipses and lines, I can accomplish my task fairly easily. The problem arises when shapes that I know are *meant* to be circles or ellipses–and were probably drawn with that intent in whatever CAD software produced the STEP file–are represented in the BREP format as spline curves of various degree, which approximate the desired shapes perfectly well visually, and for manufacturing, but which lose the original design intent.

Curves (or "edges") in the BREP format are parameterized, and I can get positions, tangents, curvature and centre of curvature at any parameter value. So actually, detecting straight lines is easy–I just look for zero curvature along the length–and similarly for circular arcs, where I can just look for constant curvature at a number of sampled parameter values. My question is, given the same information, how can I detect elliptical arcs (they might not be complete ellipses) that are not circular? What should I be looking for? Ideally, I want the center of the ellipse (or the two foci) and the major and minor radii, but the crucial output would be the center itself.

Googling just turns up a mountain of results about doing the opposite, i.e. approximating conics using splines (as the CAD software does to begin with). Nobody seems to want to reverse the process!

Comment: First, make sure the set of points of the edge in question is planar.  Then take five points from the edge and fit an ellipse to them, then compute the error between the fitted curve and the edge.  If this error is very close to zero, then the edge is indeed elliptical.

Comment: Thanks @Potato, I'll try that. I can implement the coplanar test easily enough. Just need to find an accessible description of how to do the fitting part. I'm new here, but should yours be an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: I'll write an answer in the coming hours.

Comment: Doesn’t OpenCascade have a function for constructing a conic curve through 5 points? If it does, apply it to a well-distributed set of five points from your data. Then check to see if the other points are within tolerance of the conic. Then you need to do a bit more work to figure out if the conic is an ellipse.

Comment: @bubba If it does have such a function, I've not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the set of points $\{ P_i(x_i, y_i, z_i) \}$ of the original curve.

First step is to ensure that these points lie on one plane.  This should be straight forward.  Next you want to find the $2D$ coordinates of $\{ P_i \}$ in a reference frame attached to the plane in which the points lie.  Let the unit normal vector to the plane be $n$, then one can find (in infinite ways) two vectors $u_1, u_2$ such that $u_1, u_2, n$ form an orthonormal triple, i.e. they constitute a coordinate frame.  Define

$R = [u_1, u_2, n ] $

If the coordinate frame has its origin at $P_1$ then

$P = R Q + P_1$

So that $Q = R^T (P - P_1) $ is the coordinate vector in the coordinate frame specified by $P_1$ and $ R$.  The $Q$ vector always has its third coordinate equal to zero.  So we are only concerned with the first two entries of the vector $Q$.

Now take five points $P$'s and find the corresponding $Q's$, you will have five ordered pairs $(x_i, y_i), i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 $

Using the determinant definition of an ellipse, for any point $(x, y)$ on the ellipse the following is true:

$\begin{vmatrix} x^2 && xy & y^2 && x && y && 1 \\
 x_1^2 && x_1y_1 & y_1^2 && x_1 && y_1 && 1 \\
 x_2^2 && x_2y_2 & y_2^2 && x_2 && y_2 && 1 \\
 x_3^2 && x_3y_3 & y_3^2 && x_3 && y_3 && 1 \\
 x_4^2 && x_4y_4 & y_4^2 && x_4 && y_4 && 1 \\
 x_5^2 && x_5y_5 & y_5^2 && x_5 && y_5 && 1 \end{vmatrix} = 0 $

If the edge points $\{ P_i \}$ truly describe an ellipse, then any of these points $P$ when transformed as above, generates an ordered pair $(x,y)$ that satisfies the above determinant equation.  You don't have to compute the whole determinant for each $(x,y)$, you can compute the coefficients of $x^2, xy, y^2, x, y, 1$ (by computing the cofactors of the above determinant) so that you have ready the equation of the ellipse

$A x^2 + B xy + + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0 $

This is much simpler to evaluate for each ordered pair $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. Intelligenti pauca's approach is probably simpler for me for getting just the centre of the ellipse, as I think more clearly in terms of constructions and vector operations than matrices and equations, and also has the advantage that after having done the coplanar test I can just work with 3D vectors and don't have to project down to 2D. However, your approach will give me more information, of course, so I may go with that if the centre point turns out not to be enough for my analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB$ be any chord of the ellipse, $a$, $b$ the tangents at its endpoints and $P$ the intersection of $a$ with $b$. If $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, then line $PM$ passes through the center of the ellipse.

Hence you can find the center from any two chords. And you can check with other chords if you get the same result (otherwise the curve is not an ellipse).

Moreover, the midpoints of any two parallel chords of an ellipse are aligned with the center: this is another property which could be useful to find the center of the ellipse.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need, thank you! I will implement it and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Just be careful to check that it is the *ray* PM rather than the *line* that passes through a fixed point; otherwise hyperbolas will pass too (though, if I understand it right, we are talking about curves close to ellipses, so it shouldn't be a really big concern). Another interesting question is exactly how sensitive this particular property is to small perturbations, i.e. if everything is of size 1 and the curve is not $\varepsilon$-close to any ellipse arc, by how much the lines PM will deviate from a fixed point.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Thanks again. I implemented that yesterday and it was intuitive (for me) and worked a treat.

Comment: @fedja thanks for the extra hint about the direction of PM.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca [disconnected with this question] I just saw this morning that the question about projection of a tetrahedron on a plane to which both of us had respnded no longer exist (most probably been erased by the author). Do you know by chance a way to recover it in order to recover my answer ? Thanks.

Comment: @JeanMarie Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318823/area-of-projection-of-tetrahedron/4319566#4319566 It was deleted by a mod because it's from an ongoing contest.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Ah, that's it ! Thank you very much.

Comment: This test will detect conic section curves. Then you need to do a bit more work to determine whether or not the conic is an ellipse.

Comment: @bubba Of course, but in the question they are described as "shapes that I know are meant to be circles or ellipses".